# Variable selection in R package data.table : $ vs [,,]

Tags: r, data.table

I'm curently using R package `data.table` to process big datasets.
I'm wondering if there is a difference between the syntax

```
DT[,v]
```

and the syntax :

```
DT$v
```

if `DT` is my `data.table` object and `v` the variable I want to select.

I know that the dollar sign is usually used for data frames and that `[,v]` is always used in `data.table` examples. However they both work and seem to give (in my experience with 5million rows) similar times to execute.

Do you know if they are processed differently and if one is more efficient when processing even huger datasets ?

Comment: In `DT$v`, the `$` is processed in base R and in `DT[, v]`, the `[, v]` is processed by `[.data.table`

Comment: Matt Dowle, the author of the package, says `[[` and `$` are preferred, since they don't copy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835576/class-of-data-table-column/18835813#comment27788236_18835813

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it faster to evaluate in \`j\` than with \`$\` in a \`data.table\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956250/why-is-it-faster-to-evaluate-in-j-than-with-in-a-data-table)

Comment: I think the correct way to ask a question is to first invest some effort in it by creating a reproducible example, doing some research and conduct some speed tests and then ask according to your findings. In here you are expecting us to do all the hard work for you including creating a reproducible example, testing, digging in documentation/source code, etc. This question is both useful but have no research effort which triggers me to both upvote and downvote.